# Half filled circle marker

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I draw a half filled circle on my axis. I would like the marker to be at the origin and be filled on the left half of the circle.

```
\documentclass[12pt,]{article}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

%what i want my marker to look like         
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
   \clip (0,0) circle (1cm);
   \fill[black] (0cm,1cm) rectangle (-1cm,-1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}

%what the graph looks like and the marker looks like
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    minor tick num=1,
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = middle,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$\dot{x}$},
    ymin=-5, ymax=5
    ] 

    %\draw[thin] (axis cs:1,0) circle [radius=3pt] node[above left] {$(1,0)$};
     \draw[fill] (axis cs:0,0) circle [radius=3pt] node[below right] {$(0,0)$};             
     \addplot [smooth,blue, mark=none,
      domain=-5:5] {x^2}; 
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's an existing marker `halfcircle*` rotated. Can you complete your example to a compilable TeX document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

As per @percusse's comment you can use `mark=halfcircle*` and apply a rotation as shown at `(0,0)` below.

Alternatively, you could adapt your version and define a custom macro to place this as desired  (as shown at `(1,1)`).  This has the advantage that there is no `fill` applied to the white portion.  Furthermore, you can use this technique to create any other marker type that you want to highlight special points.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

%%what i want my marker to look like         
%  \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
%   \clip (0,0) circle (1cm);
%   \fill[black] (0cm,1cm) rectangle (-1cm,-1cm);
%  \end{tikzpicture}
%  
\newcommand{\MyHalfCircle}[3][0.4ex]{%
    % #1 = size
    % #2 = x coordinate
    % #3 = y coordinate
  \begin{scope}
   \draw (axis cs:#2,#3) circle (#1);
   \clip (axis cs:#2,#3) circle (#1);
   \fill[red, opacity=0.75] (axis cs:#2,#1) rectangle (axis cs:-#1,-#1);
  \end{scope}
}

%what the graph looks like and the marker looks like
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    minor tick num=1,
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = middle,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$\dot{x}$},
    ymin=-5, ymax=5
    ] 

     \addplot [smooth,blue, mark=none,thick,  domain=-5:5] {x^2}; 
     \addplot [mark=halfcircle*, mark options={rotate=90}] coordinates {(0,0)}; 
     \MyHalfCircle{1}{1};
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```